# Spring 3 MVC JSON REST response based on header

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to get Spring to return JSON strings from a RESTful service when someone calls it accepting JSON. I'm following some of the examples here. The method looks as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@RequestMapping(value = "/**", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public String someMethod(@RequestBody String url, HttpServletRequest request) {
 ....
}
```

When I `curl` this method, I'm getting a `Error 415 Unsupported Media Type`

```
curl -i -H "Accept:application/json" 
http://localhost:8080/the/url/here
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Length: 1429
Server: Jetty(8.0.0.M2)

<html>
...
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the Jackson JARs in your classpath?

Comment: I have the Jettison JARs, I guess it's either or?

Comment: Never used Jettison, or whether it interferes with anything.  If you have the Jackson JARs on your classpath and specify an object in your `@ResponseBody`, Spring will auto-magically convert the object list to JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

415 means the media type of the request entity isn't supported. I'm guessing that since you sent no entity at all but the controller specifies an @RequestBody, it's actually complaining that you didn't send any content where content is required.